# Accessing my Spring session from a JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, javabeans

So, I'm using Spring, and I have the following in my spring-servlet.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true" />
</bean>
```

So I have this session object, thingy.  I'm actually not certain exactly what to call it.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"cpSession"})
public class MyController {

    /**
     * This controller uses this aforementioned proprietary session object
     * 
     * @return A MyControllerSession 
     */
    @ModelAttribute("cpSession")
    public MyControllerSession createForm() {
        // Instantiate the session object
        MyControllerSession sess = new MyControllerSession ();
        return sess;
    }
```

This sess object has a method I'd like to call, .myMethod().

I'd like to call that method from a JSP.

Here's what I've got:

```
<%
    MyObject mo = cpSession.myMethod();
%>
```

My IDE, eclipse, is telling me that cpSession can't be resolved, which is probably right since I don't know how to access this session object thing.

What exactly is MyControllerSession and how can I access it from a JSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%
    MyObject mo = ((MyControllerSession) session.getAttribute("cpSession")).myMethod();
%>
```